# A function that copies all items in an array into a new array for reference types

Tags: arrays, swift, types, copy, map-function

When I create an array and add some objects (reference types) to it:

```
let myArray = [UILabel(), UIButton(), UIView()]
```

I can create a **copy of the array by copying all its items**:

```
let myCopiedArray = myArray.map{ $0.copy() }
```

When I modify any of the items in `myCopiedArray` it won't have any effect on the original `myArray`.

As the `map(_:)` function is always a little difficult to read I would like to wrap this copy operation into a separate function with a more expressive name:

```
extension Array where Element: AnyObject {
    /// Creates a new array that contains a copy of each of the receiver's items.   
    func newArrayByCopyingItems() -> Array {
        return map{ $0.copy() }
    }
}
```

This doesn't the work and the compiler doesn't contribute to my understanding what I did wrong:

> `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> _' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'`

**Is there anyone who can give me a more helpful advice? ;)**

*(I suspect that somehow the compiler cannot infer the type `AnyObject` for the parameter `$0` though it's explicitly defined in the extension declaration.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnyObject` does not have a `copy()` method declared for it.

I'll explain the steps I used to come up with an answer. Maybe that will help.

Starting with: `let copiedArray = myArray.map { $0.copy() }`

I first looked for a protocol that had the `copy()` method declared on it, but I didn't find one. The most general class I found with the method was NSObject, so it looks like I'll have to go with that. Then I looked at the type of `copiedArray` by option clicking on it. I found that it is an `[Any]`. So that means I end up with:

```
extension Array where Element: NSObject {
    func newArrayByCopyingItems() -> [Any] {
        return self.map { $0.copy() }
    }
}
```

Not very pleasant, but it is what it is. I can make it more useful by creating my own protocol. The upside with this is that I can maintain the type of the copied array. The down side is that I must make sure that all the types I want to use with it conform to the extension...

With the code below, I can now do:

```
let myArray = [UILabel(), UIButton(), UIView()]
let myCopiedArray = myArray.newArrayByCopyingItems()
```

And `myCopiedArray` will be an array of UIViews without me having to cast them.

```
protocol Copying {
    associatedtype Copied
    func makeCopy() -> Copied
}

extension Array where Element: Copying, Element.Copied == Element {
    func newArrayByCopyingItems() -> [Element] {
        return self.map { $0.makeCopy() }
    }
}

extension UIView: Copying {
    func makeCopy() -> UIView {
        return self.copy() as! Copied
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the late reply. My main issue was that I interchanged `AnyObject` with `NSObject`. The latter _has_ a `copy()` function, the first does _not_. Personally, I wouldn't go with the protocol because it creates another copy function that's non-standard which makes it's really easy to get confused.